# How to export a bks keystore on Debian 7.9 wheezy

Tags: debian, java, android, webserver, tomcat

I need to generate a keystore.bks file to use for android development. I cannot figure out how to export a bks keystore without using a GUI tool. I have server space on Google Compute Engine which I am connecting to through SSH. There is no GUI option that I know of.

I set up HTTPS on Tomcat doing the following:

```
Run $JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA
You will have to answer a few questions. Most are intuitive. But:
Specify same passwords for both: key store and key.
After completion you will have new key store with new key.
As the next step you must edit $CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml file: Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keystorePass="your_password_from_step_3" />
```

I did that stuff; now I need to export my keystore as keystore.bks and I cannot find a way to do it -- at least not something I can understand. I am extremely new to Linux and really need it to be spelled out; 1. download using this command "blah blah blah" 2. run this command "blah blah blah". Sorry for being inept, but I am very much struggling to accomplish something I think is probably relatively straightforward.

These are the instructions I was given:

1. Go to http://portecle.sourceforge.net/ and download Portecle
2. Open your JKS keystore via Portecle
3. Export your certificate
4. Create new BKS keystore
5. Import your certificate and save BKS keystore as "keystore.bks"
6. In android app replace keystore.bks file by your just created BKS keystore
7. In app.properties modify "server.ssl.keystore_password" as you need

Unfortunately I cannot execute portecle in my Linux install because it does not have a GUI. I tried to load the installer to the server and run java -jar portecle.jar and it failed:

> Dec 19, 2015 2:33:37 AM java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$1 run
>   INFO:  Created user preferences directory. Exception in thread
>   "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.HeadlessException: No X11 DISPLAY variable
>   was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it. at
>   java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:204)
>   at java.awt.Window.(Window.java:536) at
>   java.awt.Frame.(Frame.java:420) at java.awt.Frame.(Frame.java:385) at
>   javax.swing.JFrame.(JFrame.java:189) at
>   net.sf.portecle.FPortecle.(FPortecle.java:342) at
>   net.sf.portecle.FPortecle$CreateAndShowGui.run(FPortecle.java:6537) at
>   java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311) at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756) at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97) at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709) at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703) at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726) at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Answer (score 1):

From Tomcat's [How-To](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Prepare_the_Certificate_Keystore):

> $JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA
>
> This command will create a new file, in the home directory of the user
> under which you run it, named ".keystore".

Thus, keystore is just a file. So, you can download it onto your local machine. If you use Windows, you can use [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) for this purpose. And then you will be able perform necessary manipulations locally.